# Eclipse plugin for software metrics - workspace level summary

Tags: java, eclipse, metrics, workspace

I found and experimented with ecliple plugin that provides software metrics for my java code.
However, this plugin works on a project level - analyzing each project separately.

Does anyone know any eclipse plugin that calculates metrics AND does the summary for all projects in the workspace? This would be a much more useful tool for me, as my workspace contains more than 70 rojects as of now...

Answer (score 1):

Not so sure of any plugin that would retrieve metrics for your projects at a workspace level. I had a similar issue and I used [Metrics 1.3.6](http://metrics.sourceforge.net/)

This one supports Headless operation from Ant and you can export the data in xml format. What I did was to create a small script file to execute all the project ant file (that had this metrics task) from command line. That worked for me. I had about 85 odd projects to work with.

As for the creation of ant file, well i generated for one and used a script to modify and copy-paste it for the others. I know that overall its not as easy as getting a workspace metrics generator, but well, creating a couple of script files and an ant file would not be that hard or time-consuming, in my opinion